# traced my code and it seems to be in a continous loop

Tags: python, loops

So I am trying to write a program that takes positive,negative numbers and then displays them at the end once 0 is entered,

```
pos1=0
neg1=0
all1=0
flt1=float(raw_input("enter a non-zero floating point number (decimals): "))
while(flt1!=0.0):
   if (flt1 < 0.0):
        neg1=neg1+flt1
        all1=all1+flt1
  elif(flt1 > 0.0):
        pos1=pos1+flt1
        all1+all1+flt1
print "the sum of all numbers entered is ",all1,"the sum of all positive numbers are ",pos1,
print "and the sum of all negitive numbers are ",neg1,
```

my issue is that when I actually trace it, ( if  I take say 5.0 and trace it) I see that it gets stuck on the "elif" part of the code and doesn't actually come back to ask for another number.  I am stuck on trying to figure out what I need to do for it to come back out and ask for another non-zero number. My goal is to have the user keep entering numbers til he/she enters 0 then it would take all the negatives and add them together and display them, then do the same for the positives and then display the entire sums (negs and pos) so far entering 0 works but nothing else

Edit: fixed indentation on the elif loop

Comment: You mean `all1=all1+flt1`, and you *never change `flt1`*.

Comment: you have bad indentation in `elif` block !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the `flt1=...` line inside the loop.

also, you should generally avoid float equality comparisons, although zero is ok.

and you should use whitespace (`n = 72 + 61 * x`, not `n=72+61*x`).

pseudocode:

```
while True:
    num = input
    if num > 0.0:
        do_stuff()
    elif num < 0.0:
        do_neg_stuff()
    else:
        break
```